# gnome-terminal PWD of new tab

Tags: gnome-terminal

If you cd into a folder and open a new tab, you get a new tab in the same working directory.

If you execute "cd folder;sleep 10s" instead, and you open a new tab before the sleep command finishes, the tab opens in the old folder.
Is there a way to change this?

Usecase: I want to define the alias
    alias sea='cd $(dirname $1); vim $(basename $1)'

So that if I edit a file and want to open a new tab, it opens in the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the OSC 7 escape sequence. This tells the working directory to the terminal.

GNOME Terminal, in `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` or a similarly named file, sets up your shell prompt to emit OSC 7 whenever the prompt is printed. That's how the terminal is notified in which directory it should open its new tabs or windows. After doing a lonely `cd` command the shell prints its next prompt and thus everything's updated.

What you need to do is either override the `cd` command with a function to emit this, or define your custom alias or function to emit the OSC 7 sequence with the hostname and the desired directory as the parameter. Take care of properly URI-escaping the special characters, as it's done (in newer versions) using the helper `/usr/libexec/vte-urlencode-cwd` utility.

(The hostname is there so that in case of mismatch the terminal knows that you've logged on to a remote host and therefore won't try to open the new terminal at the local counterpart of that directory.)